# Scikit-learn, image classification

Tags: scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, classification

This example allows the classification of images with scikit-learn:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html
However, it is important that all the images have the same size (width and height, as written in the comments).
How can I modify this code to allow classification of images with different sizes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to define your own Feature Extraction.

In example from above, every pixel is represent a feature. If your images of different sizes, most trivial (but certainly not the best) thing that you can do is pad all images to the size of largest image with, for example, white pixels.

Here an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142851/adding-borders-to-an-image-using-python) how to add boarders to image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. you can link to me an example?