# Generate background around an image with specific size

Tags: python, image, image-processing

I have an image that is N x N pixels and I want to surround it with a white background of size M x M pixels. How can I do that in Python?

Comment: See this very similar question for some idea of how to get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142851/adding-borders-to-an-image-using-python

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I wanted to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't really want to write a whole program and you just want to type a simple command into the Terminal, you can use ImageMagick which is installed on most Linux distros and is available for OSX and Windows.

The command would be - assuming M is 500:

```
convert input.png -background white -gravity center -extent 500x500 result.png
```

So, if you start off with this 400x400 image:

[image]

and run this, using blue because you can see that better on StackOverflow's white background:

```
convert input.png -background blue -gravity center -extent 500x500 result.png
```

You will get this

[image]

Of course, if you do want to write a Python program, just ignore me :-)