# Error with image sharpening in Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, filter, python-imaging-library

```
from PIL import Image
fp="C:\\lena.jpg"
img=Image.open(fp)
w,h=img.size
pixels=img.load()

imgsharp=Image.new(img.mode,img.size,color=0)
sharp=[0,-1,0,-1,8,-1,0,-1,0]

for i in range(w):
    for j in range(h):

        for k in range(3):
                for m in range(3):
                    l=pixels[i-k+1,j-m+1]*sharp[i]

        if l>255:
            l=255
        elif l<0:
            l=0
        imgsharp.putpixel((i,j),l)

imgsharp.show()
```

I want to apply a high pass (sharpening) filter with 3x3 mask size to a grayscale image. But I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\sharp.py", line 16, in <module>
l=pixels[i-k+1,j-m+1]*sharp[i]
IndexError: image index out of range
```

How can I fix my mistake and how can I get the image sharpening to work in this code?

Answer (score 5):

The specific error you mentioned is because you are not dealing with the borders of the image. A solution is to [pad the image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11143078/3991470) or deal with the width and height limits. For example: replace `i-k+1` and `j-m+1` by `max(0, min(w, i-k+1))` and `max(0, min(h, j-m+1)))` respectively.

There are other issues with your code:

- The element of the filter you are accessing is not right... you probably meant `sharp[3*m+k]` where you wrote `sharp[i]`.
- Are you using colored or greyscale image? For colored images, `l` has 3 dimensions and can't be directly compared to a single number (0 or 255).
- Also, the clipping of `l` value and the `putpixel` call should be inside the innerest loop.
- Your kernel looks a bit odd. Is that 8 supposed to be a 5? Or maybe a 9 and 0 become -1? Take a look at [kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) and at [this example](http://setosa.io/ev/image-kernels/).
- This implementation with several nested loops is not very efficient.

I recommend the following solutions to your problem.

If you want to sharpen the image and that's all, you can use `PIL.Image.filter`:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter


img = Image.open('lena.png')
img_sharp = img.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
img_sharp.show()
```

If you do want to specify the kernel, try the following with `scipy`. Be sure to take a look at [convolve documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html).

```
from PIL import Image

from scipy import ndimage, misc
import numpy as np


img = misc.imread('lena.png').astype(np.float)  # read as float
kernel = np.array([0, -1, 0, -1, 5, -1, 0, -1, 0]).reshape((3, 3, 1))

# here we do the convolution with the kernel
imgsharp = ndimage.convolve(img, kernel, mode='nearest')
# then we clip (0 to 255) and convert to unsigned int
imgsharp = np.clip(imgsharp, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)

Image.fromarray(imgsharp).show()  # display
```

Another approach is to use OpenCV. Take a look at [this article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/07/25/convolutions-with-opencv-and-python/). It will clearify things about many implementation details.

Comment: What a useful answer. I wish I could upvote this twice.

Answer (score 0):

We can sharpen an RGB image with `scipy.convolve2d` as well. We have to apply the convolution separately for each image channel. The below code shows the same for the lena image

```
from scipy import misc, signal
import numpy as np

im = misc.imread('../images/lena.jpg')/255. # scale pixel values in [0,1] for each channel

print(np.max(im))
# 1.0
print(im.shape)
# (220, 220, 3)

sharpen_kernel = np.array([[0, -1, 0], [-1, 5, -1], [0, -1, 0]])
im_sharpened = np.ones(im.shape)
for i in range(3):
    im_sharpened[...,i] = np.clip(signal.convolve2d(im[...,i], sharpen_kernel, mode='same', boundary="symm"),0,1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(10, 20))
ax[0].imshow(im)
ax[0].set_title('Original Image', size=20)
ax[1].imshow(im_sharpened)
ax[1].set_title('Sharpened Image', size=20)
plt.show()
```

[image]

We can use the gaussian kernel to first blur the image and subtract from the original image to get a sharpened image as well, as shown in the following code:

```
from scipy import misc, ndimage

im = misc.imread('../images/lena.jpg') / 255 # scale pixel values in [0,1] for each channel    

# First a 1-D  Gaussian
t = np.linspace(-10, 10, 30)
bump = np.exp(-0.1*t**2)
bump /= np.trapz(bump) # normalize the integral to 1

# make a 2-D kernel out of it
kernel = bump[:, np.newaxis] * bump[np.newaxis, :]

im_blur = ndimage.convolve(im, kernel.reshape(30,30,1))

im_sharp = np.clip(2*im - im_blur, 0, 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(10, 20))

ax[0].imshow(im)
ax[0].set_title('Original Image', size=20)

ax[1].imshow(im_sharp)
ax[1].set_title('Sharpened Image', size=20)

plt.show()
```

[image]