# How can I add a picture frame/border to multiple images from the same folder in python?

Tags: python, mask

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142851/adding-borders-to-an-image-using-python)

I need to be able to do this to multiple images from the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import glob, os
os.chdir("/")
for infile in glob.glob("*.jpg"):
    file, ext = os.path.splitext(infile)
    im = Image.open(infile)
    add_border(im)

import Image
def add_border(im):
    old_im = im
    old_size = old_im.size

    new_size = (800, 800)
    new_im = Image.new("RGB", new_size)   ## luckily, this is already black!
    new_im.paste(old_im, ((new_size[0]-old_size[0])/2,(new_size[1]-old_size[1])/2))
    new_im.show()
    # new_im.save('someimage.jpg')
```

> @credits:
>
> - http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm
> - [Adding borders to an image using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142851/adding-borders-to-an-image-using-python)